# Error in FFMpeg and png images (glob/libavformat)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFMpeg to produce an animation based on several png images
that don't follow a sequence number. With
[the following command line](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

```sh
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 mov.mp4
```

I obtain the following error

```
ffmpeg version N-53033-g56ba331 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 13 2013 22:18:29 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
--enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r
--enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray
--enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc 
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp
--enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex
--enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc
--enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 
--enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 31.100 / 52. 31.100
  libavcodec     55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavformat    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 65.100 /  3. 65.100
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[image2 @ 0268b600] Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not 
supported by this libavformat build
'*.png': Function not implemented
```

I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: From the [image file demuxer docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2): "`glob` is only selectable if libavformat was compiled with globbing support". I'm not sure what that means for Windows users but it might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

As you
[can see here](http://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6e073dd/configure#L3988),
for globbing to work you need `glob.h`.

From my quick looking MinGW-w64 does not contain this file, so you would need to use a Cygwin compiler. However this might not be desirable because the resulting FFmpeg would require the Cygwin dll.